# Права запуска Tomcat в Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat

Установил Tomcat через apt-get

Папка /usr/share/tomcat8 имеет права

> drwxr-xr-x    5 **root**   **root**  tomcat8

Внутри соответственно так же.
Запускаю Tomcat

> $ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start   Using CATALINA_BASE:
>   /usr/share/tomcat8/   Using CATALINA_HOME: /usr/share/tomcat8/   Using
>   CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat8//temp   Using JRE_HOME:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64   Using CLASSPATH:
>   /usr/share/tomcat8//bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8//bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   touch: невозможно выполнить touch для
>   '/usr/share/tomcat8//logs/catalina.out': Отказано в доступе
>   /usr/share/tomcat8//bin/catalina.sh: 401:
>   /usr/share/tomcat8//bin/catalina.sh: cannot create
>   /usr/share/tomcat8//logs/catalina.out: Permission denied

Посмотрел разные инструкции, надо типа сменить пользователя

В одной инструкции так:

> sudo chown -R tomcat8:tomcat8 /usr/share/tomcat8/logs
>   sudo chmod -R u+rw /usr/share/tomcat8/logs

в другой так:

> udo chgrp -R tomcat8 /etc/tomcat8
>   sudo chmod -R g+w /etc/tomcat8

Как оно вообще должно быть, от кого запускаться процесс и какие права на папках?

> /usr/share/tomcat8
>   /var/lib/tomcat8
>   /var/log/tomcat8
>   /etc/tomcat8

Comment: манипуляции с правами на файлы/каталоги внутри каталога `/usr` — точно не нужны и вредны. вне зависимости от того, что вы там поставили и запускаете.

Comment: проблема не только в том кто владеет папкой, а еще и в том кто запускает catalina.sh, нужно привести в соответствие эти разрешения, у запускающего должны быть соответствующие права на запись в нужные каталоги, сейчас их похоже нет.

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/security-howto.html вот выдержка из мануала, Tomcat should not be run under the root user. Create a dedicated user for the Tomcat process and provide that user with the minimum necessary permissions for the operating system. For example, it should not be possible to log on remotely using the Tomcat user.Мне не ясно как например пользователю tomcat8 дать привелегии, как он будет вести запись логов если права получит только на запись.